# CSS style on Input not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these codes and the styles are not working.
Please any clue?

HTML

```
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="bet_player()" value="Click to Start Betting"></input>
```

CSS

```css
.button {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: So we're all supposed to just figure out what "not working" means?

Comment: works just fine - http://jsbin.com/lokoqifota/edit?html,css,output

Comment: it is not working on my browser. I wonder what is wrong.

Comment: That's some pretty basic CSS - I can't think of any browser not supporting those.. are you using Linx or smth? :)

Comment: im using windows, yes i know its basic that is why I wonder what is wrong. I even tried to run it at other browser.

Comment: windows is not a browser...

Comment: I thought you asked me if i'm using Linux. My browser is google chrome, and I even tried it at IE and Firefox.

Comment: Your CSS is wrong. You have `)` instead of `}` at the end of the `#p1cash, #p2cash` style block, so the `.button-testing` block is ignored. If you click on **Tidy** in jsfiddle you'll see the problem.

Comment: You should use an IDE or editor that automatically inserts matching braces or checks for proper matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is invalid:

```css
#p1cash, #p2cash {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
**)** --- here should be }
```

and there is no `font-color` property - it's just `color`

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bdk6uv9y/2/)

Comment: OMG!! Thank you! Thank you so much! I didn't notice that parenthesis! and will keep your advice in mind. Thank you! its working now.

Comment: I would suggest to use some kind of editor with decent code highlighting, so you can spot this kind of issues right away

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jhddfngt/1/

Can you post a link to the live version? There is a good chance that you're having conflicting CSS elsewhere.

If you can't share the link, try using a class that isn't commonly used:

HTML:

```
<input class="button-testing" type="button" onclick="bet_player()" value="Click to Start Betting">
```

CSS:

```
.button-testing {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Conflicting CSS? I bet he just didn't link his CSS properly. And one more thing: input tag should not be closed.

Comment: @RoboRobok - hahahaha, you're absolutely right. I literally just copy and pasted his html. Wasn't verifying the closing of it. Updating now.

Comment: So, how do I post it live for you guys to see? I've been solving this matter for hours now. :( I know my code is fine.

Comment: Is it hosted somewhere? If so just post the link? If it's local, you'll either have to recreate it in JSFiddle or something similar.

Comment: @JerleyGarcia Check if your CSS file is ever loaded.

Comment: Here is my code guys, https://jsfiddle.net/bdk6uv9y/

Comment: Should input 500 above on the cash prompt.